# Clickonce updater tool

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

We need an updater in our software. I thought of using "ClickOnce", but I know that the ClickOnce deployer does not allow you to write information in a registry. 
Can we use ClickOnce without a deployment tool and use only the updater tool? 
Because I want to write some data into the registry during installation time, and I also want to use ClickOnce for updating purposes (because it's easy to use).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually check for updates from your code and then update

```
ApplicationDeployment updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
UpdateCheckInfo info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
//
if (info.UpdateAvailable)
{
  updateCheck.Update();
  MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
  Application.Restart();
}
```

Check this [article](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce.aspx)